# Error: Unable to index into an object of type in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Below is powershell script.

```
$Requests = Get-WmiObject -Class SMS_UserApplicationRequest -Namespace root/SMS/site_$($SiteCode) -ComputerName $SiteServer  |  Select-Object User,Application,CurrentState,Comments | Sort-Object User
    $Count = @($Requests).Count
        for ($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++) {
            if ($Requests[$i].CurrentState -eq '1') {
                $Requests[$i].CurrentState = "Pending"
                $checkbox1.Enabled = $true
            }
```

when I execute the script I am getting following error.

```
 Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject.
if ($Requests[ <<<< $i].CurrentState -eq '1') {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

What I want to do is I am replacing value (1) to Pending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `Get-WmiObject` returns just a single instance, `$Requests` will be a single object, not a collection. Enclose the `Get-WmiObject` call in the array subexpression operator (`@()`) to have it return a single-item array instead:

```
$Requests = @(Get-WmiObject -Class SMS_UserApplicationRequest -Namespace root/SMS/site_$($SiteCode) -ComputerName $SiteServer  |  Select-Object User,Application,CurrentState,Comments | Sort-Object User)
```

Comment: I like `[Array]$Request = Get-WMIObject ...` better.

Answer (score 3):

You could try dealing with each object as it exits the pipeline, instead of trying to put them all into some sort of array and then dealing with them. E.g. something like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class SMS_UserApplicationRequest -Namespace root/SMS/site_$($SiteCode) -ComputerName $SiteServer `
  | Select-Object User,Application,CurrentState,Comments `
  | Sort-Object User `
  | ForEach-Object {
        If ($_.CurrentState -eq '1') {
                $_.CurrentState = "Pending"
                $checkbox1.Enabled = $true
            }
    }
```